# How do I parse JSON from a file in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, json, parsing

I am trying to parse data from a JSON file. I am trying to put that parsed/fetched data into a UIView with a label or in a webview. 
The JSON file looks something like the following:

```
{"bodytext": "<p>\n Some lines here about some webpage (&ldquo; <em>Site</>&rdquo;) some more lines here. \n </p>\n\n <p>\n some more stuff here </p>
}
```

There are posts here on Stack Overflow showing how to parse JSON retrieved from a Web URL, but I actually already have a JSON file I want to parse.  How do I parse JSON from a file?

Comment: Just made the json file an html file and read it and displayed it on the web view. If anyone has a better way of doing this, please comment and let me know.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

1. Create empty text file (New File/Other/Empty) e.g. "example.json"
2. Paste json string into the file.
3. Use these lines to get the data:

   ```
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"json"];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
   NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
   ```

Comment: I copy pasted this snippet more than 100 times in the last month

Comment: @lucaslt89 time to make it an Xcode snippet: http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/

Comment: or maybe some helper class/category

Answer (score 18):

Swift 2.0 version of the accepted answer:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("example", ofType: "json"), data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
        }
        catch {
            //Handle error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I have followed this and it is working fine

```
NSError *error = nil;
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"messages" 
                                                      ofType:@"json"];
 NSData *dataFromFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
 NSDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromFile
                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                        error:&error];
 if (error != nil) {
  NSLog(@"Error: was not able to load messages.");
  return nil;
 }
```