# NSArray with contents of file not work in ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a JSON array from a JSON file in iOS. The problem is the code is not working
The content in JSON file is:

```
[{a:"m",data:"1597,144",tick:1},{a:"m",data:"1595,144",tick:1}, ...]
```

This is my Swift code:

```
  if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "json") {
     let array = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: filePath)
     println("\(array)")
  }
```

The file exists at path but for some reason its not working. I get `null` when I try to print the array.

Comment: From the documentation: 
`aPath The path to a file containing a representation of an array produced by the writeToFile:atomically: method.`
That is to say - it only reads files created that way, not arbitrary text files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,If I want to achieve this function ,what shall I do?  @Grimxn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: filePath)` will only work with property lists:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

What you have is JSON string. If you want to load array from JSON file check out this:
[How do I parse JSON from a file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520949/fetching-parsing-data-from-a-json-file-in-ios)

Comment: I have try the code in [Fetching/Parsing data from a json file in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520949/fetching-parsing-data-from-a-json-file-in-ios) , the result is return error `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No string key for value in object around character 2.) UserInfo=0x1458ba90 {NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 2.` Maybe can not found key in JSON file, The content in JSON file is an array

Comment: I guess JSON keys need to be strings. Try validating your JSON with http://jsonlint.com/