# Add json file and print in console

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I know how to create a dummy json data and to print them in console like below code:

```
 NSArray *jsonObject;
    jsonObject = @[@{@"Id1":@"mad",
                     @"people1":@"300"},
                   @{@"Id2":@"normal",
                     @"people2":@"9",@"total2":@"300"}];

    NSError *err;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];



    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];


        NSLog(@"%@,%@",jsonArray);
```

I have one file name **Areafiles.JSON**. In that file I have some json data. I directly drag and drop in my project.

How can I read and print in my console like my above example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching/Parsing data from a json file in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520949/fetching-parsing-data-from-a-json-file-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

For Swift:

Suppose you have a Json file titled **a.json** in your project that looks something like this:

```
{
"person":[
          {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": "16",
            "employed": "No"
          },
          {
            "name": "Vinny",
            "age": "56",
            "employed": "Yes"
          }
        ]
}
```

Now just follow the three simple steps:

1. Read the file
2. Convert the contents of the file into an NSData
3. Convert the NSData into JSON object

Now you are free to use the Json object as you please:

```
    // Get the path to the JSON File
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("a", ofType: "json")
    {
        // Load the contents of the file into an NSData object
        if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
        {

            do {

                // Serialize the jsonData object to make a Json object
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

                if let persons : NSArray = jsonResult["person"] as? NSArray
                {
                    // Print the contents of your file
                    print(persons)
                }

            } catch {
                print("Problem converting jsonResult to dictionary")
            }
        }
    }
```

Its the same process in both Swift and Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Once you drag & drop a file in your project, the file goes in your application bundle. So you need to get the path of the file on the application bundle.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Areafiles" ofType:@"json"];
```

Now you are ready to load its content on a string

```
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Then you want to obtain a dictionary from that string

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

File -> NSData

```
// get path to the file
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Areafiles" 
                                             ofType:@"json"];
// NSData from the filepath
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

NSData -> NSDictionary

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fileData
                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                            error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
      NSLog(@"%@", jsonDict);
      return jsonDict;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error reading JSON file");
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: if i print in my console using NSLog(), its not printing the json data

Comment: with out that if and else statement ., if i print "jsonDict" its working .why with that if and else its not printing

Comment: @james have you checked the error? does it print "Error reading JSON file"?

Comment: no i removed that if , else code and i print directly print with nslog (jsonDict)

Comment: in if statement error says. in viewdidload does not return any thing..... so both " return JsonDict " and "return nil " is getting error

Comment: @james Well, yes. if you use this in viewDidLoad it's natural than you get errors. Therefore you have to either remove "return" statements or move all this code to a separate method with a return type NSDictionary*